# Node.js, stream pipe output data to client with socket io-stream

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, stream, pipe, output

Sorry for a repeating topic, but i've searched and experimented for 2 days now and i haven't been able to solve the problem.

I am trying to live stream pictures every 1 second to a client via socket.io-stream using the following code:

```
var args = [
    "-i",
    "/dev/video0",
    "-s",
    "1280x720",
    "-qscale",
    1,
    "-vf",
    "fps=1",
    config.imagePath,
    "-s",
    config.imageStream.resolution[0],
    "-f",
    "image2pipe",
    "-qscale",
    1,
    "-vf",
    "fps=1",
    "pipe:1"
];
camera = spawn("avconv", args);    // avconv = ffmpeg
```

The settings are good, and the process writes to stdout successfully. I capture all outgoing image data using this simplified code:

```
var ss = require("socket.io-stream");
camera.stdout.on("data", function(data) {
    var stream = ss.createStream();
    ss(socket).emit("img", stream, "newImg");
    // how do i write the data-object to the stream?
    // fs.createReadStream(imagePath).pipe(stream);
});
```

"socket" comes from the client using the socket.io-package, no problem there. So what i am doing is that i listen to the stdout-pipe for the "data" event. That data gets passed to the function above. That means that at this stage "data" is not a stream, its a "`<Buffer .. .. ..`"-object, and therefore i cannot stream it like i could previously using the commented createReadStream-statement where i read the image from disk. **How do i stream the data (Buffer at this stage) to the client? Can i do this differently, perhaps not using socket.io-stream?** "data" is just one part of the whole image, so perhaps two or three "data"-objects need to be put together to form the complete image.

I tried using "stream.write(data, "binary");" which did transfer the Buffer-objects, problem is that there is not end of stream-event and therefore i do not know when an image is complete. I tried registering to stdout.on "close", "end", "finish", nothing triggers. Am i missing something? Am i making it overly complex? The reasoning behind my implementation is that i need a new stream for each complete image, is that right?

Thanks alot!

Comment: Checkout [simple-stream-socket](https://github.com/laggingreflex/simple-socket-stream) which is a wrapper around socket.io-stream that makes it easier to use (disclaimer: I wrote it)

Comment: Thank you for your response, i will keep it in mind if i can't solve the output stream issue and have to go back to reading from disk.

Comment: Just pipe the `camera.stdout` stream directly to the socket stream: `camera.stdout.pipe(stream)` (instead of doing `camera.stdout.on('data')`)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, i just tried it and it does stream the data to the client. The problem of when each image ends and the next one begin seem to persist still, there are no "end" events i've been able to listen to. I suppose i can buffer all data on the server and do some checking there, and then streaming it to the client.